# How do I gain root command line access to a TP-Link TL-R605 router?

Tags: command-line, router

I want to gain full command line access to administer my TL-R605 router in addition to the web interface (which provides limited configuration options).

Tried to SSH into the router, but SSH doesn't provide full access to the filesystem either.

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: SSH is the commandline interface. Are you logged in as the root user though? Not sure you can even get that. May need to replace the firmware before this is even possible.

Comment: @LPChip There's an option to create an account during first boot, which allows me to define my own username and password, and as far as I know this is the only user set throughout the Web UI, similar to OpenWRT. There may be another root user within the system that's inaccessible to the user, but I don't have much info on the underlying system though.

Comment: Interesting device. I found a user manual, but the only mention of SSH is to allow remote access for support personnel. For end users only GUI is provided. In a larger deployments it can be managed with an SDN controller. I didn't find it in any WRT-based OS support list either. That seems pretty conclusive to me - there is no command-line access for end users.

Comment: @peregrino69 Yeah, there's SSH remote access, which when enabled allows me access to the CLI, but I'm pretty certain it's not the entire filesystem, just a subset of it. Somehow PPTP got enabled recently, but it's shown as not configured within the web UI. Reflashing firmware via the web UI does not fix it either. Please feel free to post your thoughts, I'm going through the manual and SSH again. Will update if I find anything interesting.

Comment: Do you SSH using telnet or putty, or do you use the tplink SSH client?

Comment: @LPChip I'm using SSH via Terminal on a Mac. The router is connected to my Mac via Ethernet, and I SSH via terminal at the router's IP address.

Comment: Maybe you need the Tether app. See: https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/faq/2462/

Comment: Ok made some progress. I can confirm that ssh does not allow access to the entire filesystem. I.e /etc, /proc and various other default Linux folders isn't accessible. Only /bin, /sbin, /lib and /usr is accessible. Also, while commands like ps isn't allowed, I can list them by exporting the diagnostics file via the web UI. It essentially is a dump of running ps. Can also confirm that the user does not have access to root, which runs separately in the background.

Comment: Update: Managed to get access to the firmware and can confirm that it's running a slightly modified version of OpenWRT. Embarrassing thing is that it's running OpenWRT version 14.07, which was released 7 years ago and kernel version 3.10. Very strange for a product released in 2020 that claims to be a business grade security product. Can't fault the hardware so far, but software certainly needs work.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to enable "Remote Assistance" which apparently enables SSH access.  Then SSH into your router

ssh user@routerIP

I noticed on a mac that Ventura no longer accepts lower hashes so you have to update the ssh config file on Mac's (and perhaps other Distros) with the following:

sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config

then add to the bottom:

HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa <<enter new line as I don't know how to edit in this forum>>
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Then Save.

When you log in you have to enter the command EN (to enable, similar to a cisco router)

From there, type help.

Thats as far as I've gotten.  Help shows a bunch of config and show options.

After you have entered "en" for enable, you can enter "configure" to get to config options.  Type help after Configure,  lots of options there.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I tried this. Added the two lines to /etc/ssh/ssh_config in the "Hosts *" section. And I am still getting "connection refused". I have Remote Management enabled but I'm thinking that perhaps I need to set a specific subnet mask to make it work. Does anyone have any input on this?

Comment: @JDA3 it's not remote management, it's remote assistance. It's under System Tools > Diagnostics > Remote Assistance tab. Enable it and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, confirmed working. I don't see a way to make use of linux commands though it seems likely they're hiding somewhere. "(config)#" is clearly not a proper shell.